# Corona SDK / simple Stopwatch (milliseconds/seconds/minutes)

Tags: lua, coronasdk, mobile-application, stopwatch

right now I am programming a mobile app. I use **Corona SDK**.

I want to make a **simple stopwatch**. It should count up in milliseconds, seconds and minutes. I googled it already but all examples I found weren't working for me.

I know there is a way to program a stopwatch but my idea would be very costly. I know Corona is great and I believe that there is a simple and good way to solve my problem. :)

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Questions asking for general help or recommendations are off topic for Stack Overflow. Please see: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). It is expected that you have researched your issue and made a good attempt to figure it out for yourself. If you have a *specific* question, include a summary of what you have tried and the relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Without going in too much detail here, you could use this to count the milliseconds:

```
local milis = 0
local incrementMilis = 100
local watch

local function updateTime()
    milis = milis + incrementMilis
    --Have some condition to cancel the timer to avoid it running forever
    if someCondition == true then
        timer.cancel(watch)
    end
end

--trigger every 100ms, call 'updateTime' function, and loop forever (-1)
watch = timer.performWithDelay( incrementMilis, updateTime, -1 )
```

Convert the `milis` variable however you want to display it by using some simple math functions. This you should be able to figure out yourself and there's enough code and examples online on how to do this.